# connection reset by peer in java

Tags: java, php, xampp, tomcat7, jersey-2.0

**Scenario**:-

Client application - JavaScript based

Front-end processing -  PHP hosted on Apache using XAMPP(php 5.3.8, xampp 1.7.7, Apache 2.2.21)

Back-end processing - Java REST APIs hosted on Tomcat

**Description**

Browser send post data to php server , php validate and the modifies the post data according to it's need and then open a connection to back-end server(tomcat server hosting Jersey REST APIs) using curl , tomcat server then return the response to php which in-return is sent to the browser.

**Problem i am facing** :-

Tomcat server takes about 3 to 10 min to process the request(depending on the payload and type of request, higher the payload more is more is the execution time). When a higher payload request or time-taking request (7-10 mins) API is called a socket exception occurs stating "connection reset by peer" at the tomcat hosted REST APIs (Backend). Nothing happens at the front-end processing php logic. As connection is reset so Java REST API cannot send the response and as there is nothing happening on php so cannot course-correct anything happening.

Now, if same time-consuming or payload wise API call is made through a REST Client (Chrome Extension) then APIs processes normally and return the response to REST Client. So it zeroes down to any issue on php or Apache front.

**Already Tried**:
in httpd-default.conf -

KeepAlive on

Timeout 2100

KeepAliveTimeout to 2100

in php curl call -

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,20);
or 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
                array('Content-Type: application/json ',
                    'Content-length: '.$len,//length of content
                    'Connection: keep-alive',
                    'Keep-Alive: 2100'));
set_time_limit(0);
```

xdebug turned off
default_socket_timeout = 2100

and have played with a lots of combination, but no successful result.

Note - There is nothing in Apache and Php log file or any exception occurring in Php script so I even cannot drill down where the issue is coming.

**EDIT**:

I have noticed that even ajax is not getting any error, just keep on waiting for ever. If Apache is resetting the connection then ajax should also receive connection reset error.

Comment: It's a small edit but could you could you change pear to peer in the tile otherwise it seems like you got a fruit tree stuck in your connection. Also could you post the log lines with the reset by peer message?

Comment: Thanks Trudbert didn't see that :D

Comment: yes that is a typo and no it does not give anything. I tried to debug the code                                                     `try {
    $RESULT = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!$RESULT) {
        $message = 'Error :' . curl_error($ch) . '- Code: ' . curl_errno($ch);
        throw new CurlException();
    } else {
        // some code
    }
} catch (CurlException $exc) {
    error_log($exc->getTraceAsString(), 3, $destination);
}`  and placed debug point at if () statement, but it never executed